# How can I integrated Shotgun api and Javascript webview?

Tags: javascript, api, shotgun

I want to integrate RV shotgun webview(API) using Javascript.

I don't know how to do that. It might to complicated to understand. If you know about RV, you will understand what I am trying to ask.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this,

```
rvsession.evaluate("play()")
```